How to setup laravel cronjob on aws elastic binstack
On my local environment, the cron job works fine when I execute 'php artisan schedule:run', but after setting it up on AWS, this command doesn't seem to be triggering. Can anyone help troubleshoot?
File structure
[Project root]
    |-- .ebextensions
    |        |-- cronjob.config

cronjob.config
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"

Kernel.php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command(DeleteRecord::class)->everyMinute()->onOneServer();
    }

environment

PHP 8.0
Laravel 9

